# James $\ell_1$-theorem: problem in the proof

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, banach-spaces

I am struggling with the very last estimate in the proof of James' $\ell_1$-theorem. (Please see below an excerpt from Albiac and Kalton's fantastic book *Topics in Banach space theory*.)

> I don't see what kind of manipulation with indices $i,j$ is done in order to arrive at the final estimate.

Also,

> where exactly we use the assumption that $(x_n)$ is equivalent to the canonical basis of $\ell_1$?

[image]

Comment: In the last line, replace "$y_j$" with the expression on the RHS of the third displayed equation (the definition of $y_j$), then apply the inequality in the second display.

Comment: There still we a problem with $b_j$ as we need $b_j$ rather than $|b_j|$. Also I don't see where we use the assumption that $(x_n)$ is eq. to the canonical basis of $\ell_1$.